# How to convert Image to File in Flutter?

Tags: image, file, flutter, dart, type-conversion

I am writing this flutter code where I have Image in an Image widget and I want to convert it into File so that I can upload it to Firebase Storage.

```
Image _image = Image.asset('assets\images\profile.png');
File _fileImage = convertToFile(_image);
//upload _fileImage to Firebase Storage code
```

I need the `File convertToFile(Image img)` function.

Comment: @Uni I'm not picking image from photos or camera. It's present in the assets folder.

Answer (score 9):

Special thanks to [sami kanafani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640295/sami-kanafani).

This is my solution (works perfectly for me):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class ImageUtils {
  static Future<File> imageToFile({String imageName, String ext}) async {
    var bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/$imageName.$ext');
    String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    File file = File('$tempPath/profile.png');
    await file.writeAsBytes(
        bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));
    return file;
  }
}


class AnotherClass {
    File imagePlaceHolder;
    _setPlaceHolder() async {
         this.imagePlaceHolder = await ImageUtils.imageToFile(
         imageName: "photo_placeholder", ext: "jpg");
    }

    ...
    Image.file(this.imagePlaceHolder),
}
```

Comment: What is this part of your code doing? 
```String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    File file = File('$tempPath/profile.png');
await file.writeAsBytes(
        bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));```

Comment: Is the path where you will put the file (profile.png) and the bytes.buffer.asUint8List(.. is the responsible to write the "in memory file" to the device.

Comment: Hello @JavierHeisecke, this line: `(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path` only gets the temporary path directory inside app, `File` creates an empty file and `file.writeAsBytes` just get the data bytes provided previously and save them in the empty file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, and used this guide:
https://medium.com/@mrgulshanyadav/convert-image-url-to-file-format-in-flutter-10421bccfd18 (written by Gulshan Yadav)

Using these imports:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
```

And this function:

```
Future<File> urlToFile(String imageUrl) async {
// generate random number.
var rng = new Random();
// get temporary directory of device.
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
// get temporary path from temporary directory.
String tempPath = tempDir.path;
// create a new file in temporary path with random file name.
File file = new File('$tempPath'+ (rng.nextInt(100)).toString() +'.png');
// call http.get method and pass imageUrl into it to get response.
http.Response response = await http.get(imageUrl);
// write bodyBytes received in response to file.
await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
// now return the file which is created with random name in 
// temporary directory and image bytes from response is written to // that file.
return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the asset not the image

You need to install [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin

```
  var bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets\images\profile.png');
  String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
  File file = File('$tempPath/profile.png');
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));

  return file;
```

Comment: Does not work. Throws this error. [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.xyz/cache/images/profile.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: try to replace the \ with /

Comment: Getting this error. It is returning null. The following assertion was thrown building UserSignUpScreen(dirty, state: _UserSignUpScreenState#e96f8):
'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 826 pos 14: 'file != null': is not true.

Comment: found the issue, remove the /image from the file constructor, i edited the answer

Comment: how to create png to jpg, please suggest. Thanks.