# App showing wrong File, after converting base64 to File

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to convert a Uint8List to a File.

TL;DR: My backend sends me a base64 String, and I'm trying to show that in my app.

> What's the problem?

1. I first see my profile picture
2. I change my profile picture and send it to my backend which gets the new profile pictures and saves it
3. I reload the screen and the old profile picture is shown, whe I debug and check the base64 String sent by my backend I can see I'm receiving the new profile picture, even though the old is shown
4. To see my changes I restart the app manually

[image]

> About the code

- widget.profilePicture has the base64 String
- _storedImage is what I show in my app
- '${tempPath.path}/profile.png' is where I store it in the cache, this part I found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368886/how-to-convert-image-to-file-in-flutter)

```
    File _storedImage;
    Future _initialImage;
    final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    
    @override
    void initState() {
      _initialImage = _initiateStoredImage();
      super.initState();
    }
    
    Future _initiateStoredImage() async {
      Uint8List bytes = base64Decode(widget.profilePicture);
    
      final tempPath = await syspaths.getTemporaryDirectory();
    
      _storedImage = File('${tempPath.path}/profile.png');
      await _storedImage.writeAsBytes(
          bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));
    }
```

I use this method to store the image

```
Future _getImage(bool fromCamera) async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
        source: fromCamera ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery);
    File imageFile;
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    } else {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _storedImage = imageFile;
      }
    });
    final tempPath = await syspaths.getTemporaryDirectory();
    final savedImage = await imageFile.copy('${tempPath.path}/profile.png');
    widget.onSelectImage(savedImage);
  }
```

To render the image I use this widget

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _initialImage,
  builder: (_, dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.connectionState ==
        ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      if (dataSnapshot.error != null) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('Algo salio mal'),
        );
      } else {
        return Container(
          width: 150.0,
          height: 150.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: _storedImage != null
                    ? FileImage(_storedImage)
                    : AssetImage(
                        "assets/images/default-avatar.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: Alignment.center),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter's `ImageCache` caches `FileImage`s based on file path. If you're overwriting the original file, the path won't change, so Flutter will continue drawing the cached image.  In that case, you will need to call the [`evict` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider/evict.html) first to remove the cached version.