# How to convert Image object to File object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the Image object:

```
PickedFile imageFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery,maxWidth: 1000,imageQuality: 100);
Image rrimage = Image(image: ResizeImage(FileImage(File(imageFile.path)),height: 224,width: 224));
```

And I want to convert the Image object (rrimage) into a File object. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Image to File in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368886/how-to-convert-image-to-file-in-flutter)

Comment: @AlexHartford No in this question the image is an asset. In my case it's not an asset. Please check the code I've edited it.

Comment: Why not use the `image` package: https://pub.dev/packages/image The example on the front page seems to be what you want to do: read  file, resize it, store it back as a file.

Comment: @RichardHeap Yes I did try using that method. But for some reason, the copyResize function reduces the quality of the image. The ResizeImage class does resizing perfectly. And this ResizeImage object can't be casted to the Image class of this image package. It can only be casted to the Image class of the native Image widget class.

Answer (score 0):

Update

`File('out/thumbnail-test.png') ..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(rrimage));`

Comment: Yes but I want to use ResizeImage as well that's the problem

Comment: Why you want resize image exactly?

Comment: @ShowTime I need 224x224 image for running it on a machine learning model

Comment: Well in that case you can resize your image in python before you run the model. Is that works for you?

Comment: Actually I'm not using Python anywhere. I've used Tflite converter to convert my model to model.tflite. Then I'm loading the model in my dart code and giving it the image.

Comment: Okay try this way

Comment: I tried it but it throws an error. For the encodePng method we've to import the "image" package. The rrimage used in the question is an instance of the Image widget. Whereas the encodePng function expects the input to be an Image object of image package.